how to make my program loop back to a specific line in python
I'm trying to make this code go back to the top of the program instead of ending at the printed string after the first if statement.
num_1 = (input("Please enter a whole number: "))
num_2 = (input("Please enter a second whole number: "))
if num_1.find (".") != -1 or num_2.find(".")!= -1:
   print("sorry enter a whole number")
else:
  print("numbers are whole perform the calculation")
  num_1 = int(num_1)
  num_2 = int(num_2)

  print(f"{num_1} + {num_2} = {num_1 + num_2} ")

I have tried everything I can think of, but I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated.
i got this far now but the program just repeats even with the break keyword
while True:  
  num_1 = (input("Please enter a whole number: "))
  num_2 = (input("Please enter a second whole number: "))
  
  if num_1.find (".") != -1 or num_2.find(".")!= -1:
    print("sorry that isnt a wole number")
  else:
    print("numbers are whole perform the calculation")
    num_1 = int(num_1)
    num_2 = int(num_2)
    print(f"{num_1} + {num_2} = {num_1 + num_2} ")
    break


put it in a for or while loop, but you need to consider when/how you would want to exit the loop, otherwise it could repeat forever.  If you use a for loop, you could easily get it to repeat only n times, however you could use a while loop to repeat until the user enters a specific string or something

Have you learned about the break keyword yet?

i just ran your newer code, and it works correctly. Did you remember to save your file?

You can use a while loop to achieve that!
while True:
  num_1 = (input("Please enter a whole number: "))
  num_2 = (input("Please enter a second whole number: "))
  if num_1.find (".") != -1 or num_2.find(".")!= -1:
    print("sorry enter a whole number")
  else:
    print("numbers are whole perform the calculation")
    num_1 = int(num_1)
    num_2 = int(num_2)

    print(f"{num_1} + {num_2} = {num_1 + num_2} ")

However, doing this will make your program repeat infinite times. You can add a custom condition to break the loop:
  repeat = input("Do you want to go again?")
  if repeat!="y":
    break

Or you can use a for loop to run the code as many times as you want:
for i in range(n):
  num_1 = (input("Please enter a whole number: "))
  num_2 = (input("Please enter a second whole number: "))
  if num_1.find (".") != -1 or num_2.find(".")!= -1:
    print("sorry enter a whole number")
  else:
    print("numbers are whole perform the calculation")
    num_1 = int(num_1)
    num_2 = int(num_2)

    print(f"{num_1} + {num_2} = {num_1 + num_2} ")


hi thanks for the answer, it works but the program just repeats even with the break keyword

If for some reason the break keyword does not work, use bool variable.
Here is an example -
run = True
while run:  
  num_1 = (input("Please enter a whole number: "))
  num_2 = (input("Please enter a second whole number: "))
  
  if num_1.find (".") != -1 or num_2.find(".")!= -1:
    print("sorry that isnt a wole number")
  else:
    print("numbers are whole perform the calculation")
    num_1 = int(num_1)
    num_2 = int(num_2)
    print(f"{num_1} + {num_2} = {num_1 + num_2} ")
    run = False

